# How much do sheep cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, animals, pricing

How much does it cost to buy a sheep? I can't find this information anywhere. I've looked at the equipment tables in the PHB don't see any sheep.

Comment: "This question does not show research effort" is the tooltip on downvotes.  For something that's trivially in the rules, it might be best to say where you looked to give people some assurance you actually looked anywhere.

Comment: @mxyzplk you're totally right, I'd actually seen the table linked below but not read it properly. My mistake but hopefully will be useful for future visitors.

Comment: If you edit that into the question (that you actually did look in that section of the PHB) I bet some of the downvotes will go away.  You have to understand, the site does get plagued with folks who have apparently never read anything but a charavter sheet asking rules questions and so the suspicion of that generates some community pushback.

Comment: Sorry, but price-shopping questions are off-topic. They tend to be very location-specific and go out of date quickly. ;-)

Comment: Why would the sheep be in the equipment table?

Answer (score 53):

The "Trade Goods" section of the PHB (pg. 157) states that a sheep is worth 2gp.

Comment: Actually it’s considered better form not to give page numbers, as different translations, printings, etc. can vary.  Thaat’s actually been a WotC rule for citations in times past and even on this site we get a lot of “but it’s not on page X...” for that reaason.

Comment: Is the discouragement on page number citations in the meta somewhere? I usually cite by section or chapter and section, but when a point is difficult to find that way, I'll use page numbers.

Comment: I don't give page numbers mostly because of D&D Beyond, and the existence of the basic rules and the SRD. There are simply too many different page numbers to give. Chapter and section are universal.

Comment: @HaakonLøtveit A joke alluding to racial strife doesn't really enhance the site. Best to avoid such things.

Answer (score 36):

Sheep are worth 2gp according to the Trade Goods table in the Equipment chapter of the Players Handbook or basic rules.

Answer (score 15):

The Trade Goods section in Chapter 5 of the PHB and [Basic Rules](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules):

> **Cost.........Goods**
>
> 1 cp..........1 lb. of wheat
>   2 cp..........1 lb. of flour or one chicken
>   5 cp..........1 lb. of salt
>   1 sp..........1 lb. of iron or 1 sq. yd. of canvas
>   5 sp..........1 lb. of copper or 1 sq. yd. of cotton cloth
>   1 gp..........1 lb. of ginger or one goat
>   **2 gp......1 lb. of cinnamon or pepper, or *one sheep***
>   3 gp..........1 lb. of cloves or one pig
>   5 gp..........1 lb. of silver or 1 sq. yd. of linen
>   10 gp........1 sq. yd. of silk or one cow
>   15 gp........1 lb. of saffron or one ox
>   50 gp........1 lb. of gold
>   500 gp......1 lb. of platinum

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71925/discussion-on-answer-by-spellcaster-how-much-do-sheep-cost).